# PHP form action is not linking

Tags: php, forms, action, redirect

i am trying to create a form. but the  is not directing to the edit.php in my theme. I use different theme, so not a theme problem. 
Whenever i clicked the submit button, it said "Not Found
It looks like nothing was found at this location. Maybe try a search?"

This is a very simple, but I just could not figure it out. I try  . I put it on my front-page.php. I put it on different page.php. It just said NOT FOUND. I also try to create a function on the edit.php and try to call it like this " but then it will wipe out everything on the page.

```html
<form action="edit.php" method="POST">
 File Name: <input type="text" name="name"><p>
  <input type="submit" value="edit">
  </form>
```

my edit.php like this

```html
 <html>
<form action="" method="POST">
 Enter Text:<br><textarea name="edit" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea><p>
  <input type="hidden" name="file_name" value="<?php  ?>">
<input type="submit" value="save">
</form>
</html>
```

Please help. I know it is very simple. But i try every way, I just could not figure out this simple question.

Comment: Where is edit.php in relation to your calling script? Maybe in a different directory? If so you'll need to include that in your action attribute. Or just use the absolute path

Comment: Why have you got 2 forms on the pages? Where is the processing php?

Comment: Is `<?php  ?>` right? If so, huh?!?